# Why does Rhino Mocks error on a stub, but not on the exact same thing as a mock?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm fairly new to rhino Mocks, just started using it this project.

I am testing some code which calls an external method to get an IEnumerable of 'Project', which I've got an interface for it so that I can stub/mock it out.

at the start of my unit test that tests some of the code that iterates over (or calls Count(), both cause the error) that IENumerable, I setup a stub implementation

```
IJobProcess stub = MockRepository.Stub<IJobProcess>();
SetupResult.For(stub.CheckTeamMeetingInLastMonth(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true);
SetupResult.For(stub.GetOutstandingActions(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(
                    new List<ProjectActionsDomain.DomainObjects.ProjectAction>()
                    );
```

This however results in:

```
PmqccFormTests.GetFlagsReturnsIncompleteFlagWhenIncomplete : FailedSystem.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IEnumerator.MoveNext();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source)
at PmqccDomain.DomainObjects.PmqccForm.GetFlags() in PmqccForm.cs: line 387
at PmqccUnitTests.PmqccFormTests.GetFlagsReturnsIncompleteFlagWhenIncomplete() in PmqccFormTests.cs: line 426
```

However, if I change this to

```
        IJobProcess mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IJobProcess>();

        mock.Expect(x => x.GetOutstandingActions(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(
            new List<ProjectActionsDomain.DomainObjects.ProjectAction>());
        mock.Expect(x => x.CheckTeamMeetingInLastMonth(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true);
```

It does not error, I thought a stub was a mock that didn't assert on its results basically? or am I wrong there? What does Rhino Mocks do differently that avoids the error when using a mock?

Comment: Can you post the code at line 387 within PmqccForm.cs.

Comment: That line of code simply calls the IJobProcess interface which Rhino mocks is stubbing/mocking out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jonny C has highlighted I believe that SetupResult is not compatible with MockRepository.GenerarteStub.

SetupResult seemsed to be used with the expect-record and playback functionality that Rhino used before lamba expressions were used.

The preferred way is to use the Arrange-Act-Assert syntax that was introduced later however when looking at the Rhino API it is hard to tell what to use for AAA.

What I do is to only stub methods/properties that need to return a value and assert that methods were called at the end.

so what should work is...

```
//Arrange
IJobProcess stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IJobProcess>();
stub.Stub(x => x.CheckTeamMeetingInLastMonth(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true);
stub.Stub(x => x.GetOutstandingActions(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(
                new List<ProjectActionsDomain.DomainObjects.ProjectAction>()
                );   
//Act
-- Perform SUT --

//Assert
stub.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CheckTeamMeetingInLastMonth(someExpectedValue));
```

[useage of SetupResult](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+Setup+Result&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

[usage of AAA](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2008/05/16/rhino-mocks--arrange-act-assert-syntax.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the AAA syntax is a bit confusing, so much in the API seems to do the same thing, but slightly different. Like MockRepository.Stub vs GenerateStub.. confusing.  Mock.Expect got it to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly how SetupResult.For is used, but to stub a method I would normally use

```
stub.Stub(j => j.CheckTeamMeetingInLastMonth(null))
.IgnoreArguments().Return(true);
```

to do the same thing you're trying to do. mock.Stub() works for the same purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that the counterpart to

```
IJobProcess mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IJobProcess>();
```

is

```
IJobProcess stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IJobProcess>();
```

So to compare directly you might want to try stubbing that way and see if you get the error using the same syntax.

But to answer your question, yeah that's what a stub is, I don't know why that's failing (although I'm not familiar with the stub syntax you used).  There's a similar bug discussed on a [mailing list here](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.rhino-mocks/2008-08/msg00011.html), could be related to that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I just changed it from the _mockRepository variable I had to MockRepository but still get the same thing